# Windows file share under Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, nfs

I have an issue with mounting Windows file share in Cygwin.

We have Windows file share which is using NFS to share content. I was assigned to install Cygwin on it so some application can connect over SFTP to that server.

Now they need to access the shared folder from that application and the app would pull data from that folder.The thing is that the folder is Windows shared folder (exmple; \server\photos). the current Windows users need to be able to connect to that share (it is mapped to their M drive) and the app need to connect to SFTP and pull the data from there.

My idea was to mount that NFS share in Cygwin and set it as /home directory so when the app connects, it automatically goes there.

My questions are: is this possible, and does anyone know any better solutions?

I am open for all suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin views the top of its directory tree `/` to be within the Windows directory `C:\cygwin64` (or whatever its installation directory was). As a result, you are unable to move above that point in the filesystem from a Cygwin shell. The solution is to go through Cygwin's directory `/cygdrive`, which is automatically set up as the access point where all Windows disk drives are mounted. If your shared folder is mounted in Windows as `M:`, you should be able to access it in Cygwin as `/cygdrive/m` without any additional work.

As far as setting it up as `/home`, you might be able to create a symbolic link from `/home` to `/cygdrive/m` if that is what you need.